# Sharing bootstrap template with django admin

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-admin

What's the best way to share a bootstrap template between my own django app and the admin app?

I've got bootstrap working just fine for my own app - including a link in a menu to the admin app. I've also installed django-admin-bootstrapped, but that just gives me a completely separate bootstrap template.

I'd like my template to apply to both my own app and to the admin, so that my sysadmin users see the admin link and, when they're in the admin app, still see everything looking consistent and can easily get back to the main app.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just override the base admin template and use it in your app, take a look here [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

But you can use the same base file for both the admin and your app views

Comment: That looks a promising plan. I'll give it a go.